# How to save and restore (persist) a StateObject in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, codable

I'm curious, how should we save/restore the data that's in our `ObservableObject` instances that are also marked as `@StateObject`? Since they are the source of truth for whatever data they contain, naturally there's a need to save data to/from them.

I tried adding `Codable` conformance to my Observable object, and that looked promising. Saving data worked just fine, but when I tried to load the data, I discovered that `@StateObject` makes the property that contains the `ObservableObject` a get-only property. So I can't use the `init(from:)` initializer to load a new instance and override the property with it. (Xcode error: "Cannot assign to property: 'myStateObject' is a get-only property")

So how should I solve this? One solution I can think of is to create an intermediate struct that holds all the data in the ObservableObject, make that conform to `Codable` and save and load data using that struct, then transfer the values to/from the `@StateObject`. But this is very messy and a source of massive code duplication (and is prone to bugs).

Only slightly better would be to create a new instance as I now have, then copy the relevant values over from the new instance to the state object, member at a time. This will side-step the get-only property issue and by eliminating the need for the intermediate structs will reduce the code duplication, but it's still not great. What are some better ways?

Comment: You could use `CoreData`, with all the objects already conforming to Observable.
 Then it is relatively easy to save and re-load the data, and
 use it like any other `ObservableObject` with their published values.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, that's pretty close to the first solution that I laid out, but I think that it would remove the duplication by adding a level of indirection. So I would bind to state data as `$myStateObject.dataStruct.name`. Conceptually, this is fine, but I'll have to see if I can pull this off. My state data is complicated already (it's a subclass of a generic). I wish I'd known about these issues before I gone so deep down this path. But thanks for the suggestion! I'll think on it.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine, I think CoreData is really not the best tool for this. This is truly State data, so I'd be adding single row tables to CoreData for each StateObject that I'm trying to persist.

Comment: Suit yourself, since this is more of an opinion based question/answer, I still believe `CoreData` 
is the way to go. `Core Data also helps keep your views and data synchronized by providing data sources for table and collection views.`
  see: [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata)

Comment: It certainly makes pragmatic sense. Core Data gives us plenty of features. I think it's a solution to consider. I don't know enough about CoreData to avoid some of the baggage, though. eg how to disable history for the state-related tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing up this answer based on the comments in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75713619/14840926) from [Lorem Ipsum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12738750/lorem-ipsum).

For small amounts of state data, you could use the [AppStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage/) or [SceneStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenestorage/) to store things in [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults). This is designed to store very small amounts of data of certain types (NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary) in per-device persistent storage.

Here's a couple of files showing how you could do this. By adding Codable and RawRepresentable conformance to your ObservableObject, you enable the option to use the `@AppStorage` decorator. It will take care of storing and retrieving the data at the right times, including initialization.

StatePackage.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

class StatePackage: ObservableObject, Codable, RawRepresentable {
    @Published var label = "Text"
    @Published var icon = "questionmark.app"
    
    // Explicit default initializer needed because other inits prevent the
    // automatic compiler-generated initializer
    init() {}

    // The next three items are to conform to Codable
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case label, icon
    }
        
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        label = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .label)
        icon = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .icon)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(label, forKey: .label)
        try container.encode(icon, forKey: .icon)
    }
    
    // The next two items are to conform to RawRepresentable
    required init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(StatePackage.self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        label = result.label
        icon = result.icon
    }
    
    var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("StatePackage") var statePackage = StatePackage()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Label", text: $statePackage.label)
            TextField("Icon", text: $statePackage.icon)
            
            Section("Preview") {
                Label(statePackage.label, systemImage: statePackage.icon)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by someone in the comments (since deleted), separating the data that needs to be persisted into a separate Codable struct will allow us to use the Codable mechanisms to save/load that data without running afoul of SwiftUI's plumbing. If your data is easily rearranged in this way (mine isn't) and you don't mind an extra level of indirection during access (I wouldn't), this can be a good solution.

Here's some code showing an implementation of this.

ContentView.swift (note all the extra ".data" indirections):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var statePackage: StatePackage = StatePackage()
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Label", text: $statePackage.data.label)
            TextField("Icon", text: $statePackage.data.icon)
            
            Section("Preview") {
                Label(statePackage.data.label, systemImage: statePackage.data.icon)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            if phase == .background {
                statePackage.saveToStore()
            } else if phase == .active {
                statePackage.loadFromStore()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and StatePackage.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

class StatePackage: ObservableObject {
    struct StateStruct: Codable {
        var label = "name"
        var icon = "questionmark"
    }
    
    // All of our persisting data is pushed down one level into an encapsulating
    // struct so that we can use standard Codable methods to load/save it easily
    @Published var data = StateStruct()
    
    // Defining that we save our data in the Documents folder
    static func persistentFileURL() -> URL {
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        return url.appendingPathComponent("StatePackage.json")
    }

    func saveToStore() {
        print("save to Store")
        do {
            let url = Self.persistentFileURL()
            try JSONEncoder().encode(data).write(to: url)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to save state")
            // handle this better in real code
        }
    }
    
    func loadFromStore() {
        print("load from store")
        do {
            data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.StateStruct.self,
                                            from: Data(contentsOf: Self.persistentFileURL()))
        } catch {
            // If we can't load from persistent store for any reason, fall back on default settings
            data = StateStruct()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what if the file is changed by another process? e.g. extension or an app in the same app-group. `@AppStorage` and `FileDocument` handles this automatically.

Comment: Good questions! Mainly, saving is happening only when we call saveToStore, so our extensions and apps in the same app-group should take care to not call it, if that's a problem. As for AppStorage, it might not be appropriate for larger amounts of data. I cannot comment on FileDocument, as I haven't looked into it. I will now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If your data is too big to be stored in [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), you could try using @ObservedObject instead of @StateObject, so that the responsibility for initialising and restoring the object is higher up in the hierarchy, and not using @StateObject will give you access to more Swift features that will allow you to save and restore the data.

For example, the three files below show how you could achieve the desired result by making the App object responsible for saving and restoring the object that holds your state data. The declaration for the variable holding that state (ie `statePackage`) does not have any decorator declaring that it is the source of truth, but it nonetheless is the source of truth. Semantically, there may be a problem there, but this seems to work out fine. The downstream Views do correctly use `@ObservedObject` to express interest in changes to the object, as you are already used to.

Really, it would be nice if Apple gave us a `@PersistentStateObject("StatePackage.json")` decorator that would have done the same thing.

StatePackage.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

class StatePackage: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var label = "Text"
    @Published var icon = "questionmark.app"
    
    // Explicit default initializer needed because init(from:) prevents the
    // automatic compiler-generated initializer
    init() {}

    // The next three items are to conform to Codable
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case label, icon
    }
        
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        label = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .label)
        icon = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .icon)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(label, forKey: .label)
        try container.encode(icon, forKey: .icon)
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var statePackage: StatePackage

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Label", text: $statePackage.label)
            TextField("Icon", text: $statePackage.icon)
            
            Section("Preview") {
                Label(statePackage.label, systemImage: statePackage.icon)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PersistStateObjectApp.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct PersistStateObjectApp: App {
    private var statePackage: StatePackage
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    // we load the state data from persistent storage at initialization time
    init() {
        do {
            let fileURL = Self.persistentFileURL("StatePackage.json")
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)

            statePackage = try JSONDecoder().decode(StatePackage.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            // If we can't load from persistent store for any reason, fall back on default settings
            statePackage = StatePackage()
        }
    }
    
    // The state data is saved to a file in our Documents folder
    static func persistentFileURL(_ filename: String) -> URL {
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        return url.appendingPathComponent(filename)
    }
    
    func savePersistentData() {
        do {
            let fileURL = Self.persistentFileURL("StatePackage.json")

            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(statePackage)
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to save state")
            // handle this better in real code
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(statePackage: statePackage)
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            if phase == .background {
                savePersistentData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```